# capistrano apache deployment

Tags: apache, passenger

I deployed my ror application successfully using capistrano, but when i brought up a browser point it to the application, it said 'server not found'.

here is my apache2.conf:

```
..
NameVirualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hylog.daemon.com
  DocumentRoot /home/work/hylog/current/public/

  <Directory /home/work/hylog/current/public>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

in browser i pointed it to http://hylog.daemon.com.. anyone know what might be wrong? I've installed passenger. thanks.

Comment: Dunno why someone would -1 this... however, shouldn't this be on serverfault?  (I +1'd you back...)

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the DNS entry for hylog.daemon.com is not pointing to the right place.  You should be able to ping the hylog.daemon.com and that point to the ip address of the server.

UPDATE:

format for hosts file:

```
<remote_ip> <host_name>
```

so if the ip address for the remote server was 12.12.12.12, the additional line in the host file should look like this:

```
12.12.12.12 hylog.daemon.com
```

Comment: i can ping the ip of that server, but not dylog.daemon.com, if i m not wrong, do i need to add the host somewhere in the hosts file? where can i find that hosts file? i m using ubuntun.. thanks

Comment: yeah, i edited /etc/hosts, added hylog.daemon.com as below:
127.0.0.1  localhost hylog.daemon.com

but still got the same result, can ping IP not that host...

Comment: I added the format for the host file that should get you going

Comment: no, still wont' work, actually i m running apache2 on ubuntu, which created a virtual host for a local ror application, so i think the format should just be:
127.0.1.1   hylog.daemon.com

either way, it didn't work.... i googled around and found blogs about setting up virtual host on apache2, need to enable-sites and lots of other steps, maybe that's the answer..? gosh, it's way more complex than i thought.